# If I have multiple producers producing same data to Kafka,Is it efficient to configure one topic for each producer or one topic for all producers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have more number of producers let's say around 200. and each producer have 4 different kinds of data. so is it efficient to produce data from all producers to same topic or is it efficient to configure different topic for each producer?

I want to collect each producer data separately at the consumer end.

What are the available ways to handle data at the consumer end?

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference. The broker just stores bytes; it has no knowledge of "type".

The main problem with putting everything into one topic is that your consumers will need to know how to deserialize and process those bytes, consistently. I.e. setting `value.deserializer` might not return a concrete class, but rather some generic type like JSON string or Avro GenericRecord, which then needs extra parsing and large switch-case logic in your consumer

Comment: Can you throw some more information about consumer end?

Comment: You say you have "4 kinds of data". Your consumer can only return **one** generic `Value` class. Therefore, you need some generic deserializer that can handle each type, such as types included in JSON/Avro/Protobuf libraries, rather than your own custom class definition